# Amount of requests on mapbox tile using flutter_map

Tags: flutter, mapbox, fluttermap

I have recently implemented the flutter plugin called flutter_map, using the Mapbox tiles,  and would like to know how you guys manage to count the network requests for the Static Tiles. Is it supposed to make a request for every move (zoom in, zoom out, move around, etc.) on the map itself? Is that the intended functioning or is there a way to diminish the number of requests made?[Amount of requests made after zooming/panning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLbJ1.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it supposed to make a request for every move (zoom in, zoom out, move around, etc.) on the map itself?

Yes indeed. The package supports static raster tiles, which means they must be re-downloaded if they change - such as on move or zoom events.

There isn't much in the way you can do about this, as it's a kind-of standard. This is why you'll find a similar thing in other mapping libraries, such as Leaflet.js and others.

See https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-tiles/ for potential ways to reduce costs whilst maintaining standards.